# Adding animations to an ember app without liquid fire?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, web, frontend, gsap

I've researched about the use of liquid fire and its fine, but I don't quite like to have to use different syntax for the outlets and be tied down to the use of velocity.js (I find better the use of GSAP for the management of animations in terms of control and performance) so I'm wondering what kind of mechanism could I use to animate outlet transitions, and above all deletion of models (some kind of hook that I can make wait before the record deletion).

Thanks a lot !.

Comment: This question is not on topic for SO because you haven't asked a specific programming question. See [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  You may get better results on [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: There must be hooks available. Can you put together an isolated jsFiddle or Codepen demo of the same? I have a few ideas that I would like to try out.